# template for a vector of defined struct

Tags: c++, templates, vector, struct

I have the following data structure

```
class FamilyMem
{
public:
    string name;
    string relation;

};

template<class T>
class Paerson
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    vector<T> family;

};
```

I have a vector defined as the following

```
 vector< Paerson<FamilyMem> > p;
```

I'm using this library and I want to call a function that uses templates, I'm trying to create my own version of the function but it is not working

```
 // I initialize the vector p by calling this function
 initPerson(p);

 for(int i=0; i< p.size(); p++)
     display(p[i]);
```

This is the function

```
template<class U>
struct Displaying< std::vector<U> >
{
    typedef std::vector<U> Vector;

    static void display(const Vector& v)
    {
        cerr << "Vector Size " << v.size();
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
template<class U>
struct Displaying< Paerson<FamilyMem> >
{
    static void display(const Paerson<FamilyMem> v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.family.size(); i++)
            cerr << "name " << v.family.name << " relation " << v.family.relation << "\n";
    }
}
```

For some reason it is still calling the vector version and print the size

Comment: Please spend some time formatting your code.  It is almost painful to read as is.

Comment: At the very least, for template specialization, you use `template<>` not `template<class U>`.

Comment: @MikelF Thanks!! can you post it as a solution so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing template specialization, the proper syntax for your case would be `template<>` rather than `template<class U>`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization